# PN532 I2C Connection not working

Tags: i2c

I have connected my Raspberry Pi 3b to a PN532 NFC reader using the I2C interface. I am using the [red version 3.0 board](https://e-radionica.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/s/dsc_4819.jpg). I have set the switches: 1 to on, 2 to off, as according to the table for I2C. I have connected GND, VCC, SDA and SCL correctly, the LED lights up. I have enabled I2C interface on the PI.

With all of that, triple checked, when I run `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` on the PI, it just prints an empty table and doesn't detect the PN532 board.

Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: The most likely explanation is you have not connected SDA/SCL correctly.

Comment: @joan already tried swapping, nope.

Comment: Add a photo of the connections between the Pi and the device.

Answer (score 2):

It can be that the you do not have the PN532 set to i2c mode.
Check it out how is done in the image:

[image]